# Can you do a jagged visual selection or jagged yank?

Tags: selection

given some text like

```
sadf_blahbalh_sdf
sadf_abc_zzz
asdf_yx_sdf
```

and I want to block select from the 'b' of blah down to the 'y' of yx and then, for every line extend the select to the _  using something like `t_`.   But that will select till the _ on the line with yx.  What I'd like is a jagged block select that will t_ per visual block line,  so blahbalh, abc, and yx are all selected... is this possible? or a different approach?

so that if I then yank it and then do visual block select spaces between [ ] in the below example and paste...

```
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
```

I'd end up with

```
[blahbalh]
[abc]
[yx]
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Unfortunately, the only jagged visual-blocks are ones that go to `$` end-of-line. You might be able to automate this with a macro, though. Something like `0fbmaqq`ayt_`ajmaq` (excuse the formatting, there are backticks between q/a and _/a)—this would let you run `@q` to yank a particular block. You could add commands to move somewhere else and paste if you wanted too.

Answer (score 2):

Plug-in [vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) implements multiple selections and it can do what you describe here. (It can even select multiple visual selections on lines that are not adjacent.)

See [some examples](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi#wiki) on the README, also the Wiki has specific sections, for instance one on [Motions and Modes](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi/wiki/4.-Motions-and-Modes). Once you install the plug-in, you can also find more documentation in Vim itself under [`:help visual-multi`](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi/blob/master/doc/visual-multi.txt).